# Where can I download common-annotations.jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Have a Spring 2.5 webapp which runs fine under 1.6, but under 1.5 it can't find PostConstruct class.

Found the following which suggests I need common-annotations.jar (JSR-250) but cannot find anywhere to download it

Answer (score 1):

The reference implementation is available here:
http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr250/index.html

Reference Implementation (RI) and Technology Compatibility Kit is part of [glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

In other words, you might end up having to download the GlassFish Application Server just to get the single jar file.